# Handle Exception: Failure "nth"

Tags: ocaml

In Python, it is quite simple to manage certain error with unit tests. For instance, to verify if a list is emptied or not, I can use `assert test != []`

Suppose the empty `list let test = [];;`

```
try
 ignore (nth test 0)
with
 Not_found -> print_string("Erreur!");;
   Exception: Failure "nth"
```

I need to raise an error - `print_string ("Erreur!")` when I encounter `Exception: Failure "nth"`. So far the `try/with` did not really help me. In Ocaml, is there a workaround to raise the error and print something when I get `Exception: Failure "nth"`?

Comment: `raise test != []` is not valid Python.  Perhaps you meant `assert test != []`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Python, it is quite simple to manage certain error, with unit tests. For instance, to verify if a list is emptied or not, I can use `assert test != []`

You can do exactly the same (modulo syntax) in OCaml

```
let require_non_empty xs = 
  assert (xs <> [])
```

If you would like to hush an exception and raise in its absence, you can use the match construction, here is how your example could be expressed in OCaml,

```
let require_empty xs = match List.nth xs 0 with
  | exception _ -> ()
  | _ -> failwith "the list shall be empty"
```

In addition, testing frameworks, e.g., [OUnit2](http://ocaml.github.io/platform-dev/packages/ounit/ounit.2.0.0/doc/oUnit/OUnit2/), provide special functions such as `assert_raises` for these specific cases.

Comment: Can I assert with a error message? I know it is not good, but can I say `assert(xs <> []; print_string "The list is emptied!")`. Maybe an equivalent might be `assert (let cond = (xs <> []) in if cond then print_string "List empty" ; cond)`

Comment: You can write a function, `let assert_message cnd msg = if not cnd then failwith msg`, and then use it as `assert_message (xs <> []) "shall not be empty"`. You can also define your own exceptions, as simple as `exception My_exception of string`, and again you can use OUnit2 for testing where all this primitives are already implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking whether you can test for specific exceptions. Yes. The exception handling part after `with` is a list of patterns similar to the `match` expression.

```
try
    ignore (List.nth [] 0)
with
| Not_found -> ()
| Failure s -> print_string ("Erreur: " ^ s)
| _ -> ()
```

(It probably isn't wise to depend on the exact string supplied as the argument to `Failure`. The compiler, in fact, warns you not to do this.)

OCaml also has an `asssert` expression:

```
# let list = [] in assert (List.length list > 0);;
Exception: Assert_failure ("//toplevel//", 1, 17).
```

You can use `try/with` to handle the resulting exception, of course. The argument to `Assert_failure` gives the filename, line number, and character number on the line.